# Isoecursive Types When to Fold and Unfold

Tags: type-theory, type-inference, types-and-programming-languages

I'm trying to implement recursive types into my programming language. I've implemented extensible rows and was hoping to add some recursive typing in order to get something like `this` or `self` within a record (thus imitating objects). Recursive types would only occur in record definitions, like

```
record IntObject:
  val: int
  add: (IntObject -> IntObject)
```

Now `IntObject` is an alias for the type `mu X. {val: int, add: (X -> X)}`.

This represents an `IntObject` with a field `val` that has the type of a primitive integer, and an `add` method that takes in an `IntObject` and returns another `IntObject`, so I can use it like so:

```
IntObject(1).add(IntObject(2))
```

The definition of `add` would be something like.

```
record IntObject:
  def add(self, other):
    return IntObject(self.val + other.val)
```

Like in Python, instance method invocations have a reference to the object calling the method implicitly passed in as the first parameter. I'm not sure how Python does this, but I was thinking of doing the partial application of the instance methods at object creation. Therefore,

```
IntObject(1)
```

creates a record like this (using Haskell lambda syntax)

```
{val: 1, add: \other -> IntObject.add(self, other)}
```

I tried reading TAPL's section on recursive types, and isorecursion seems much easier to implement, especially since I will only allow records to have recursive types. What I'm unsure about is when to add `folds` and `unfolds`. TAPL says

> In Java each class definition implicitly introduces a recursive type, and invoking a method on an object involves an implicit unfold.

This is exactly what I want to do. If invoking a method introduces an `unfold`, that means that there needs to be a `fold` somewhere, and I'm unsure where to introduce that `fold`.

If this question is too vague, specifically since I probably haven't given enough information about the current state of my language, a general answer would suffice. Any advice regarding where to introduce folds and unfolds in an OOP language, say Java, would help a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've stated, the type of `IntObject` is `mu X. {val: int, add: (X -> X)}`. `fold` and `unfold` witness the isomorphism between a recursive type and its body, i.e. in this case between `mu X. {val: int, add: (X -> X)}` and `{val: int, add: ((mu X. {val: int, add: (X -> X)) -> (mu X. {val: int, add: (X -> X)))}`. Letting `Y` stand for `mu X. {val: int, add: (X -> X)}`, this can be more compactly written `unfold : Y ~= {val: int, add: (Y -> Y)}` with `fold` going the other direction.

You need `unfold` whenever you want to access any fields/methods. `mu X. {val: int, add: (X -> X)}` doesn't have any fields; `{val: int, add: (Y -> Y)}` does. Dually, whenever you want to make an `IntObject`, you need to use `fold`. A value of type `{val: int, add: (Y -> Y)}` is not an `IntObject`, but `fold` can inject that value into the type `IntObject`. In particular, any time you `new` up an `IntObject`, i.e. invoke the constructor to create an object.

Basically, your `IntObject(i)` "really means" something like

```
let self = fold({val: i, add: \other -> IntObject.add(self, other)}) in self
```

Similarly, your `add` method would look like:

```
def add(self, other):
    return IntObject(unfold(self).val + unfold(other).val)
```

where we'd use the definition of `IntObject` just mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question. I'm a bit confused how this works in other cases though. If I have a function `let f = \x -> x.add`, my type system infers the type `{add: A | B} -> A`, aka any record that has an `add` field, and potentially any other fields, and it returns the type of that `add` field. I'm unsure how this would work with `IntObject`. `f(IntObject(1))` requires an `unfold` but `f({add: 1})` does not.

Comment: `f(IntObject(1))` is a type error. Presumably your point is that you don't want your users to have to (or be able to) insert these `fold` and `unfold` calls. The simplest solution is to just not have (naked) record types in the surface language. This would amount to having `fold` be incorporated into record construction and `unfold` in field access. This may cause issues with record extension. Another solution is to try to insert `fold` and `unfold` as needed. This basically amounts to a form of subtyping with all the issues that entails, but less so if you plan to have subtyping anyway.

Comment: I was hoping to try to avoid subtyping, and I do not allow for record extensions. I'm okay with having `fold` incorporated into record construction. I guess all records would then have the type `mu X. {...}`, where some records don't use `X` at all in their body. I think this makes sense. I'm still unsure how I would handle nested `unfold` calls, but I think I can figure it out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Depending on your type system it may not be too hard to introduce a limited form of subtyping to automatically unfold types (most likely recursing covariantly inside records) at applications. I think you'll need to restrict these implicit unfolds to annotated types though, otherwise small program transformations could affect the result.

Comment: You could do some special casing in your type inference algorithm. For example if something expects a mu-type and it gets something that is obviously not a mu-type (like a record), then it should fold. If it expects a record type, but it gets a mu-type, then unfold. This is easier to do in a bidirectional typechecking algorithm.
This does not work for all cases, but it could be practical enough to avoid subtyping.